# std forward and enums

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, enums

I have a custom memory allocator in which I use std::forward to forward constructor arguments. I am having problems in cases where the constructed class has a enum in its constructor.

Here is an example code to show the error:

```
class Monkey
{
public:

    enum TestEnum
    {
        TEST1 = 0,
        TEST2
    };

    Monkey(int age, TestEnum e) : mAge(age), mE(e)
    {
    }


private:
    TestEnum mE;
    int mAge;
};

template <class T, typename... Arguments>
T* AllocateObject(Arguments&&... args) { return new (malloc(sizeof(T))) T(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...); }


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Monkey* m = AllocateObject<Monkey>(100, Monkey::TEST1);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler throws these errors at me;

```
error C2065: 'TestEnum' : undeclared identifier
error C2974: 'std::forward' : invalid template argument for '_Ty', type expected
fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

What is causing this? shouldn't `std::forward` deal with this?

Comment: Looks like a bug, which version of VS? [clang++3.4
 compiles this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66af19d06ab47ebc)

Comment: Is there a reason you use placement new with memory allocated by `malloc`?

Comment: I use VS2012; I use a separate function to allocate the memory, I just replaced it with malloc for demonstration purposes

Comment: @KaiserJohaan You're probably using November CTP, which is just a preview of a new features, so bugs are to be expected. I tried it and indeed it doesn't work when variadic templates are involved. It works with VS 2013 though.

Comment: I am indeed using November CTP.

Comment: Remarks on the code: You should initialize members in the same order as they are declared in the class (GCC with -Wall gives "_warning: field 'mAge' will be initialized after field 'mE'_"). Also you example is not really [complete](http://sscce.org/): to test it, we must add includes of headers `<utility>` (for `std::forward`), `<new>` (for "placement `new`"), and `<cstdlib>` + a `using std::malloc;`. _Edit:_ Oh and `<windows.h>` (I guess), since you're not using the standard `main` function.